# How do you apply a texture to your World?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, world

I'm trying to apply a sky texture to my World by using the Node Editor, but it makes the texture become black-and-white instead of my expected result. Is there another way to apply textures to Worlds, or am I doing something wrong?

[image]

^^ This is the texture I'm trying to apply to my World ^^

[image]

^^ This is the unintended result after using the Node Editor ^^

Comment: please show the node organisation or share your file

Comment: add environment image not just image